# Riddle/Wordplay: What am I?

Tags: riddle

- 25% of me is very selfish
- Half of me is part of the crowd
- ¾ of me is all about business
- But all in all I am pretty short

Hint: I’m not very good with the metric system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One little thought is you may me

> INCH

25% of me is very selfish

> I

Half of me is part of the crowd

> In

¾ of me is all about business

> Inc. - abbreviation for an Incorporated company

But all in all I am pretty short

> Just 2.54 cm - in the metric system.

Comment: You got it! Bravo!